# How can I diagnose high CPU and RAM usage in a production Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, devops

#### TL;DR

- Node.js v16 (Docker image `node:16`) API hosted on an EC2 instance with 8 GB of RAM and two vCPUs
- CPU usage in 200% (as shown by `docker stats`)
- RAM usage in 1.1 GB (as shown by `docker stats`)
- Heap snapshot shows only 132 MB used
- The *Performance* "tab" doesn't show any CPU task running for a considerable amount of time
- Application was normally responding during the high resource usage.

#### Description

Today, our monitoring system reported an unusual 100% CPU usage in our production Node.js application running with Docker on an AWS EC2 instance.

Upon inspecting the instance using [htop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop), I identified two `node` processes consuming an excessive amount of CPU. `docker stats` further showed that the API service (in Node.js) was utilizing 200% of CPU capacity (since the instance has two vCPUs).

Throughout this event, I monitored the HTTP request durations, and they appeared normal with an average response time of 30 ms.

##### Profiling

To be proactive about potential issues, I now run the production Node.js process with the `--inspect=127.0.0.1:9229` flag.

The Chrome inspect tool displayed the Memory and Performance tabs, allowing me to collect samples during the "incident."

##### RAM (Memory tab)

While Docker reported the application as consuming 1.2 GB of RAM, the memory heap snapshot disclosed only 132 MB in the heap.

[Memory summary chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KueYf.png)

##### CPU (Performance tab)

The CPU chart did not identify any time-consuming processes. The most intensive task took only 177 ms and occurred only a few times.

#### Current status

I have not restarted the application to enable better diagnosis. Currently, CPU usage is below 10%, but RAM is still at 1.1 GB, as seen in `docker stats`.

I did not restart the application, so I can better diagnose the problem. Now, the CPU usage is below 10%, but the RAM is still at 1.1 GB, as shown by `docker stats`.

Reproducing this error for further investigation is challenging since the root cause of the high CPU usage is unknown. Interestingly, the application maintained good latency even while using 200% of CPU.

#### Conclusion

My analysis was inconclusive, and I may be doing something incorrect, leading to misleading results. I need assistance in diagnosing the CPU peak that occurred, along with the current high memory usage.

I have saved the profiling data for later analysis if required.

This post could subsequently be useful to others who are diagnosing high CPU usage in Node.js, a task that is less than intuitive.

Comment: Node.js version?

Comment: @AKX Sorry, I forgot. It's NodeJS v16 (Docker image `node:16`)

Comment: You're going to need to add more logging to your app to find out what it's actually doing, or perhaps try and reproduce the problem locally. If this Node app is responding to HTTP requests then it should be fairly straightforward to log and see what it's doing.

Comment: If node is remaining responsive, then to me that suggests you have some sub-process in node that's causing the CPU spike,  does your node app use workers or spawn processes?.  Another option for CPU spike is of course the GC, but generally speaking this should be short lived, unless you have some memory hogging process that's constantly allocating / deallocating causing the GC to be working full time on collecting.